# How to load image from URL in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-glide, android-jetpack-compose

Well, I am studying the Compose UI and I am stucking in basic things.
One of them is show a image from URL with Glide.

I have tried the below code but the delegates (onResourceReady and onLoadCleared) are not being called.

Did I miss something?

```
@Composable
fun loadPicture(url: String, contentDescription:String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

  val bitmapState = remember { mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null) }
  Glide.with(LocalContext.current).asBitmap().load(url).into(
    object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
            bitmapState.value = resource
        }
        override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}
    }
)

  bitmapState.value?.let {
    Image(
        contentDescription = contentDescription,
        bitmap = it.asImageBitmap(),
        modifier = modifier
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/. Add `implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.5.0")` to a corresponding `build.gradle` file and use `AsyncImage`.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use Coil for compose:

- https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/

Add the dependency:

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.0.0-rc01")
```

and use it like this:

```kotlin
Image(
    painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter("https://www.example.com/image.jpg"),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier.size(128.dp)
)
```

Comment: Hi, do you have any suggestions on how to have `Image` resize automatically based on the size of the asset? Like, say we don't know the dimensions of the remote image before we download it.

Comment: @Eugene just don't pass modifier with defined size.

Comment: I tried this, but I didn't have much luck unfortunately. I posted a SO question, can you take a look if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68848663/2852849