# How do I create a Jetpack Compose Image that resizes automatically based on a remotely loaded image size?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I would like to display an image with the following rules:

- The image is remote and needs to load on runtime.
- We don't know what the image size is until it's loaded.
- The `Image` view should take the full width of the parent, and it should automatically adjust its height to match the remotely loaded image, so that no cropping/stretching occurs.

I tried using the [Coil dependency](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/) and I have this code:

```kotlin
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(viewModel.fullImageUrl),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .aspectRatio(3.21428f) // TODO: Figure out how to set height/ratio based on image itself
)
```

When I remove the `Image`'s `contentScale` and `modifier`, its height always seems to be zero. I'm not sure what I should do to make `Image` fill the max width of its parent while determining its own size after Coil loads the image file.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you set flexible width with `fillMaxWidth`, you need to use `ContentScale.FillWidth` for your `contentScale`:

```
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        "https://via.placeholder.com/300.png",
    ),
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
)
```

---

The following will work fine if your image has enough priority. But in some cases `coil` won't start loading because it's gonna think that image is zero size so no need to display it. For such case you can add `size(OriginalSize)` parameter to the builder:

```
rememberImagePainter(
    "https://via.placeholder.com/300.png",
    builder = {
        size(OriginalSize)
    }
)
```

This parameter makes your view download and put into the memory full size of the image, without optimizing it for the current view. So use it **carefully**, only if you're sure the image won't be too big and you really can't add use size modifiers.

---

If image is getting loaded but still not takes enough space, you can set aspect ratio like this:

```
val painter = rememberImagePainter("https://via.placeholder.com/300.png")
Image(
    painter = painter,
    contentDescription = null,
    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .then(
            (painter.state as? ImagePainter.State.Success)
                ?.painter
                ?.intrinsicSize
                ?.let { intrinsicSize ->
                    Modifier.aspectRatio(intrinsicSize.width / intrinsicSize.height)
                } ?: Modifier
        )
)
```

If none of these helped and `painter.state` is not changing from `Empty`, try hardcode height `?: Modifier.height(10.dp)` to let image start loading

Comment: @Eugene looks like you haven't tried my latest suggestion with  `builder = { size(OriginalSize) }`, this works for you example

Comment: This solution also worked for me. Please keep in mind that it should be considered as temporary solution. This parameter makes your view download and put into the memory full size of the image, without optimizing it for the current view So use it carefully, only if you're sure the image won't be too big and you really can't add use size modifiers.

Comment: @SerhiiTereshchenko Thanks for that clarification, I added that information to my response.

Comment: ContentScale.FillWidth reduces height of the image as well.